# How to use " swiper.activeIndex " with if condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

I am using Swiper.js in my project. I want to know the current active slider.

How can I use `swiper.activeIndex` with an `if` condition?

Or, I want to write some code for when an expected slider is reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi what you need to do is to listen for the "slideChange" event of your swiper.

To learn more about the events and apis for swiper please take a look at the documentation: https://swiperjs.com/

**Heres a short example on how to do that:**

```
<script>
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
    swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
        if(this.activeIndex === 1) {
            console.log("IM ON SECOND SLIDE!");
            alert("IM ON SECOND SLIDE!");
        }
    });
    
</script>
```

**Fully working example (Code taken from demo page):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Demo styles -->
  <style>
    html, body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color:#000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .swiper-slide {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 18px;
      background: #fff;
      /* Center slide text vertically */
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');
    swiper.on('slideChange', function () {
      if(this.activeIndex === 1) {
        console.log("IM ON SECOND SLIDE!");
        alert("IM ON SECOND SLIDE!");
      }
    });
        
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Current slide index  ==> swiper.activeIndex

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).